# redirect to the previous page automatically in tcl

Tags: redirect, tcl

Is there a header redirect function in tcl similar to the header in php?

Basically when I land on a new page, I want to do some error checking,  it fails I want to redirect it to the previous page automatically( by previous page, I mean wherever the browser back button leads to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tcllib's [ncgi package](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/ncgi.html) has a redirect proc.